How do I "View sink log volume and error rates" for a _folder_ log sink?
Looking at my folder log sink when I click this:

And then I'm redirected to this page:

If metrics explorer isn't available for folders then do folder log sinks have not metrics? How do you troubleshoot them?

Metrics Explorer operates at the project level, not the folder or organization level. Therefore, you can't directly view metrics for a folder-level sink using the standard Metrics Explorer interface.
Monitoring a folder sink involves aggregating the metrics from all your Sink destination using BigQuery, Pub/Sub, Cloud storage bucket, Splunk and other cloud services to monitor your logs when metrics explorer does not work.
Make Sure before you create a Sink, to access and manage folders, you assign folder-specific IAM roles like Folder Admin Roles to specific groups of users. If you created your sink in the Google Cloud console and you have Owner access to the destination, then Cloud Logging should have set up the necessary permissions.
